# longest palindrome prefix complextity

Tags: java, complexity-theory, big-o, palindrome

What's the complexity of this algorithm? It seems at least O(n^2).

```
// civic
public static boolean isCharPalindrome(String test) {
        String stripped = test.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^0-9a-zA-Z]", "");
        for(int i = 0; i < stripped.length() / 2; i++) {
            if(stripped.charAt(i) != stripped.charAt(stripped.length() - 1 - i)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

// ILLINOISURB
public static String longestPrefixPalindrome(String test){
    String max_prefix = test.substring(0,1);
    for(int i=test.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
        String maxPrefix = test.substring(0, i);
        if( isCharPalindrome(maxPrefix) ){
            return maxPrefix;
        }
    }

    return max_prefix;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "A man, a plan, a canal, Panama!"; 
    System.out.println("isCharPalindrome:" + isCharPalindrome("A man, a plan, a canal, Panama!"));
    System.out.println("longestPrefixPal:" + longestPrefixPalindrome("NILLINOISURB"));
}
```

Comment: I removed much vertical space, and a comment ´// TODO Auto-generated method stub` Such comment is meant to be removed as soon as you touch the method, because if you do something by hand, the comment gets wrong.

Comment: sounds like [theoretical cs](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) to me

Comment: theoretical cs is not for undergrad-level questions like this. it does belong here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The complexity is O(n^2), since the complexity of `isCharPalindrome` is O(n) and you are calling it n times from `longestPrefixPalindrome`.

But you can reduce the complexity by starting with the longest prefix and then reducing the size of the prefix that is tested. If you do this, you can quit the method as soon as you find a paliendrome. You don't need to go till the end each time.

I am sure you know how to make the changes to `longestPrefixPalindrome` accordingly.

Look at @pajton 's answer though. If you think about it, you can get the complexity down to O(n). The answer I gave will actually give you a hint about that can be done.

Comment: That answer got deleted, because it didn't find prefixes like `illi` in ILLINOISURB.

Comment: yeah. but did u understand how u can make the complexity of this problem O(n) ?

Comment: No. But for arbitrary input, it isn't that worse, is it? For Nillinoisurb, a string of length 12, the method isCharPalindrom is called 12 times, but it is always searched, whether the first charachter, `N`, matches the last of the substring, and this is just once the case, and in this case there is the match. Now, you could investigate what the average Input will be, how often the first character matches another one in the substring. Of course, palindromes aren't often investigated in real life, so there is no empirical Data to reason about - we can reason about completely artificial words....

Comment: So you would find more palindroms with an alphabet of 4, 3 or 2 characters. Then you would more likely start to enter the inner loop for a while. I can of some optimizations: If you look at 'AGGT' you see immediately, that the shortest possible palindrom would be of length 7, so you should be able to skip some tests. For AGTCTG you see, that a single A would make it palindromic. However I don't see how I would do it. In real performance critical situations I would start to pull the stripping in a separate step, to do it just once.

Comment: It's not about whether in practical situations, you get the benefit or not. I mentioned this more from an algorithmic and programming stand point. If you can solve this problem in O(n), you will appreciate the beauty of such tricks. But, this is more of a hacker's delight kind of thing. Many people don't care about such stuff.

Comment: I modified the "longestPrefixPalindrome", but it seems hard to reduce it to O(n), since the "isCharPalindrome" alone is O(n).

Comment: And I mentioned the practical view to decide, whether I have to think about `typical input` or, whether I can freely invent my own input (AGGTGG). With empirical input, like random words from a dictionary, or sentences, picked from books, you will not get runtimes of O(n²), because only 1 in 26 characters on the end will match the character in the beginning. Successive steps in the inner loop follow with 1/26 probability too, if we assume evenly distributed characters.